# language change in php

Tags: php, html, session

i am trying to change the all page language but session is not working  . Session is taking previous value and language change after two click so please solve this problem.

```
$_SESSION['lanuage'] = $_POST['hindi_hidden'];

        if (!empty($_SESSION['lanuage'])){ 
            if ($_SESSION['lanuage'] =='hi')
            {         
                      $_SESSION['lanuage'] = $_POST['hindi_hidden'];
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['lanuage'] =='en')
            {     
                    $_SESSION['lanuage'] = $_POST['hindi_hidden'];  
            }
            else {}
        }
        else
         {}
<input type="button" name="hi" id="hi" value="Hindi" onclick="get_hindi(this.id);" class="submit_sytle"/>
<input type="button" name="en" id="en" value="Eng" onclick="get_hindi(this.id);" class="submit_sytle"/>
```

Comment: Have you used `session_start();` at the beginning? You have also typos in your names: `lanuage`, `submit_sytle` ...

Comment: Your input field is called `hi` and `en` not `hindi_hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

Code after your comment:

You can try this, it works for me:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['hindi_hidden'])) {
    $_SESSION['lanuage'] = $_POST['hindi_hidden'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['lanuage']) && ($_SESSION['lanuage'] =='hi' || $_SESSION['lanuage'] =='en')) {
    $_SESSION['lanuage'] = $_POST['hindi_hidden'];
}

echo $_SESSION['lanuage']; 
?>
<style>
.submit_sytle{
 text-transform:capitalize;
}
</style>
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="hindi_hidden" id="hi" value="hindi" onclick="get_hindi(this.id);" class="submit_sytle"/>
<input type="submit" name="hindi_hidden" id="en" value="english" onclick="get_hindi(this.id);" class="submit_sytle"/>
</form>
<script> 
function get_hindi(lang) {
    //alert (lang); 
    document.getElementById('hindi_hidden').value=lang; 
    document.form_login.submit(); 
} 
</script>
```

Output:

`english` when I click on English

`hindi` when I click on Hindi

Comment: <script>
function get_hindi(lang)
{//alert (lang);
 document.getElementById('hindi_hidden').value=lang;
 document.form_login.submit();
}
</script>
 <input type="text"  id="hindi_hidden" name="hindi_hidden"  value=""/>

Answer (score 0):

```
 Can you try this
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['hindi_hidden'])){
    $_SESSION['lanuage'] = $_POST['hindi_hidden'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['lanuage']='hindi';
}
echo $_SESSION['lanuage']; 
?>
<style>
.submit_sytle{
 text-transform:capitalize;
}
</style>
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="hindi_hidden" id="hi" value="hindi" onclick="get_hindi(this.id);" class="submit_sytle"/>
<input type="submit" name="hindi_hidden" id="en" value="english" onclick="get_hindi(this.id);" class="submit_sytle"/>
</form>
```

Comment: same problem remain if in session have 'hi' and i went to another page it will not change in hindi

Comment: then you try: if(isset($_POST['hindi_hidden'])){  $_SESSION['lanuage'] = $_POST['hindi_hidden']; } else if(isset($_SESSION['lanuage']) { $_SESSION['lanuage']=$_SESSION['lanuage']; }else { $_SESSION['lanuage']='hindi';}